# Quotes on Ahavas Yisroeil

Tags: quotations, ahavat-yisrael

I am looking for good quotes about Ahavas Yisroeil because of a story I am writing. Can anyone provide some nice sayings from Jewish sources?

Comment: Hatslaha rabba with the story. Unfortunately, however, this question is probably too broad.

Comment: See Noam  Elimelech on beginning of Vaera

Comment: Could you please [edit] this post to provide guidance on the qualities of the ideal quotation for your purposes? What are some objective ways that readers could judge if one suggested quotation is a better fit than another?

Comment: Regarding compassion and charity see the frst halakhot in the tenth chapter of Rambam's Hilkhot Matnot Aniyim: ג  כל המרחם--מרחמין עליו, שנאמר "ונתן לך רחמים וריחמך והרבך" (דברים יג,יח); וכל מי שהוא אכזרי ואינו מרחם, יחוש לייחוסו--שאין האכזרייות מצויה אלא בגויים, שנאמר "אכזרי המה ולא ירחמו" (ירמיהו נ,מב).

ד  כל ישראל והנלווה אליהם--כאחים הם, שנאמר "בנים אתם, לה' אלוהיכם" (דברים יד,א); אם לא ירחם האח על אחיו, מי ירחם עליו.  ולמי עניי ישראל נושאין עיניהן, הלגויים ששונאין אותן ורודפים אחריהם--הא אין עיניהן תלויות, אלא לאחיהן.

Answer (score 2):

ואהבת לרעך כמוך - רבי עקיבא אומר זה כלל גדול בתורה.(Veahavta lereacha kamocha - Rabbi Akiva omer ze klal gadol baTorah)

Comment: Great quote by R' Akiva there. Is there any source you could provide?

Comment: @EzraHoerster Talmud Yerushalmi, Nedarim 9:4